# Build method called muliple times in root widget

Tags: flutter

My root widget builds several times when I restart my flutter application. In my case 3 times. I think it should build only once after an app restart. I'm also aware that, when will be a "build method" called according to the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html). But the official reasons don't seems fit to my scenario.

Can someone please explain the theory behind this or it is just happening to me

Thank you

```
void main() => runApp(MainWidget());

class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("main build");
    return ChildWidget();
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("child build");
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Text("test"),
    );
  }
}
```

Results

```
Restarted application in 677ms.
I/flutter ( 3604): main build
I/flutter ( 3604): child build
I/flutter ( 3604): main build
I/flutter ( 3604): child build
I/flutter ( 3604): main build
I/flutter ( 3604): child build
```

Comment: if you are creating a new `ChildWidget` each time `MainWidget` is built then this is normal that `ChildWidget` is built too - otherwise you would see nothing inside `MainWidget`

Comment: @pskink thank you and I agree with your comment but why the MainWidget called multiple times? I think it supposed to be called once. correct me if i wrong

Comment: when you restart the application `main` is called again so `MainWidget` is created, then its `build` method has to be called, then `ChildWidget` is created, then ...

Comment: then again `build` called in the `MainWidget` and rebuilds its child. In my case `MainWidget` created 3 times. is there any reason for that?

Comment: ok, you made one app restart, but `MainWidget` is created 3 times?

Comment: yep that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I figured the issue. It's because of the flutter SDK version. I was using SDK ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0". When I changed the SDK version to ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" in pubspec.yaml file, builds called only once.